# How to get a users download folder in Unity WebGL?

Tags: c#, php, unity-game-engine, webgl

I have been working on a project that generates synthetic images from a user provided backgrounds uploaded to the program, and then exporting an image using the new data. I am using a webGL supported file browser to allow users to select the backgrounds, and then select the folders in which to export to, however I have been informed the project needs to be automated.

How can I get a path to the users downloads folder from a webGL build of Unity? Hard coding is not an issue since we will have control of the computers that provide or receive the images.

Do I need to host locally? I was originally using Itch.io as a host.

Comment: You do not have access to a computers file system from the browser.

Comment: I figured, can I access it if I host locally?

Comment: The option that comes to mind is a database. This can be paired with the servers file system if needed.  Essentially you would need a server and an api running on the server that you can communicate with.